# Setting up Bidirectional Replication on a Database in Always On Availability Group

Tags: replication, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

Is it possible to set up bidirectional replication on a database in Always On Availability Group?

Answer (score 1):

We can look at documentation [Replication, change tracking, & change data capture - Always On availability groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/replicate-track-change-data-capture-always-on-availability) where we can see (in the Restriction paragraph):

> Note: Does not include support for bi-directional and reciprocal transactional replication.